# Как связать базу данных mysql с сайтом html php?

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных

Есть несколько таблиц, созданных в phpMyAdmin, они вроде связались по индексу.
таблицы примерного содержания о преподавателях:

```
-ID    
-Name    
-Date    
-MonographyID    
-PublicationID
```

есть отдельно таблицы с Monographies и Publications, они связаны.
Вопрос, как представить на сайте эти списки, чтобы их можно было смотреть, изменять и т.д?

[image: picture]

Comment: К сожалению вряд ли кто-то возьмется отвечать на вопрос. Он банален, но слишком много придется объяснять. Поэтому скоро он будет закрыт. Я могу лишь подсказать, что без навыков программирования это можно сделать с помощью WordPress и плагина https://wordpress.org/support/view/plugin-reviews/tablepress

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получается, Вам нужен CRUD.
Нужно реализовать функциональность, которая будет работать с БД. Пусть это будет файл db.php. 
В нем реализуется класс (или набор функций), которые коннектятся к БД с помощью логина, пароля и хоста, делают выборку (SELECT), обновляют (UPDATE), создают (INSERT) и удаляют (DELETE). Так же должна быть функциональность, отвечающая за построение критерий.
А потом можно создавать файлы шаблонов для создания, редактирования, обновления и просмотра таблиц из БД.
Вот подробная статья по коннекту к БД и базовым запросам.
http://www.php.su/articles/?cat=phpdb&page=025